# Spinner delete items

Tags: android, listview, spinner, adapter

I have developed an application in which i have one edit text value of edit text is entered in spinner on button clicked an the item i select to delete gets deleted but the problem is that when i delete the last item of spinner whole spinner list flushes . i want to delete only selected item(only last item)

My code is as follows :

```
@Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // grab our UI elements so we can manipulate them (in the case of the
    // Spinner)
    // or add listeners to them (in the case of the buttons)
    m_myDynamicSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.dynamicSpinner);
    m_addItemText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.newSpinnerItemText);
    Button addButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.AddBtn);
    Button clearButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ClearBtn);

    // //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // create an arrayAdapter an assign it to the spinner
    m_adapterForSpinner = new ArrayAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    ((ArrayAdapter) m_adapterForSpinner)
            .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    m_myDynamicSpinner.setAdapter(m_adapterForSpinner);
    // m_adapterForSpinner.add("dummy item");

    // //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // add listener for addButton
    addButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            addNewSpinnerItem();
        }
    });

    clearButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            clearSpinnerItems();
        }
    });
}

// //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// add listener for addButton
private void addNewSpinnerItem() {
    Log.v("TAG", "addNewSpinnerItems called");

    if (m_addItemText.getText().length() == 0) {// ||(m_addItemText.getText().toString()==
        // " ")){
        Log.v("In if cndtn", "textHolder is of length 0");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "The textView is empty",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //m_myDynamicSpinner.clearFocus();
        //m_myDynamicSpinner.setFocusable(false);
        //m_addItemText.setFocusable(true);
    } else {
        CharSequence textHolder = "" + m_addItemText.getText();
        // else{
        Log.v("else", textHolder + "");
        // m_adapterForSpinner.add(textHolder);
        // }
        ((ArrayAdapter) m_adapterForSpinner).add(textHolder);
    }
    m_addItemText.setText("");
}

private void clearSpinnerItems() {
    // m_adapterForSpinner.clear();
    Log.v("TAG", "clearSpinnerItems called");
    m_myDynamicSpinner
            .setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
                        View view, int pos, long id) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Log.v("TAG", "Itemseleted to be removed is "
                            + m_adapterForSpinner.getItem(pos).toString());
                    Log.v("Position of item", pos + "");
                    Object t = m_adapterForSpinner.getItem(pos);
                    Log.v("Object t ", (String) t);

                    ((ArrayAdapter) m_adapterForSpinner).remove((CharSequence) t);
                    Log.v("Item removed", t + "");

                    // m_myDynamicSpinner.setSelected(false);
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });
    // m_adapterForSpinner.add("dummy item");
}
```

Comment: @Shruthi If u click delete button the Selected Value should be deleted but now all values getting deleted Right?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

for delete all items use:

```
mySpinner.setAdapter(null);
```

if you want to delete a particular item, remove this from m_adapterForSpinner and then:

```
mySpinner.setAdapter(m_adapterForSpinner);
```

Comment: In my case, mySpinner.setAdapter(null);
 throws an exception!

Comment: @thenosic setting the adapter to null will remove the connection between the spinner and the adapter, in fact we're trying to only remove the adapter items

Answer (score 1):

For me the accepted answer throwed an exception so what I did was this.

```
    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(),
android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, Collections.emptyList());
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember: methods "remove" and "clear" do not work with ArrayAdapter for Android 2.3.3 and lower. You'll receive error message "Unsupported operation.... bla bla bla". May be they work with Android 4.0 and up, I don't know.
Here is my solution which works even with minSdkVersion="5".

1. Create Spinner and fill it with test data 
   This code is in an activity form. Use ArrayList as data source for ArrayAdapter instead  of  array. It's important because you'll use its "remove" method later

   ```
   List<String> reportFiles = new ArrayList<String>();        
   //fill some test data     
   reportFiles.add("aaaaaaaaaaaaa");
   reportFiles.add("bbbbbbbbbbbbb");
   reportFiles.add("ccccccccccccc");

   //create spinner from corresponding layout xml file
   Spinner spnReport  = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_report);

   //create ArrayAdapter
   ArrayAdapter reportAdapter =  new ArrayAdapter(this, 
           android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,  reportFiles);

   //set adapter to spinner
   spnReport.setAdapter(reportAdapter);

   //select first item in adapter - is not obligatory
   spnReport.setSelection(0);
   ```
2. Remove selected item from Spinner

   `reportFiles.remove((String)spnReport.getSelectedItem());`

   `//create new ArrayAdapter with modified ArrayList
   reportAdapter =  new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,reportFiles);`

   `//set new array adapter to spinner
   spnReport.setAdapter(reportAdapter);`

   `//select first item
   spnReport.setSelection(0);`

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. Doing this did solve the problem, by emptying the spinner:

```
mySpinner.setSelection(Adapter.NO_SELECTION);
```