# How to hide first item from string resources file and display in a spinner

Tags: java, android, kotlin, spinner, android-spinner

How can I hide the first Item in a spinner?

My entries:

```
string-array name="super_spinner">
        <item>Select</item>
        <item>1</item>
        <item>2</item>
        <item>3</item>
        <item>4</item>
        <item>5</item>
    </string-array>
```

I want the spinner to show the first item but not when he opens the spinner options.

Comment: Are you using a default spinner?

Comment: Swap the adapter to a new adapter with less elements. how to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5988447/spinner-delete-items

Answer (score -1):

Use spinner adapter to show the items you want to show in the dropdown.
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner#java