# How to remove one option from a Spinner list that is selected in another list?

Tags: java, android

I am new to android programming. I was trying to create a Currency Converter app that has two drop-down menus having the same items in the list for both the currencies. I wanted to do such that when the user selects one option from the FROM Currency, that option automatically disappears from the TO Currency list. I tried to do something looking at clues from Google searches but it worked only on one of the options.
How can I do it???

[App Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75jIg.png)        [Code Snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4Dpg.png)

Comment: check out this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5988447/spinner-delete-items

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `toCurrencyList.remove(position)` with `adapter2.remove((String)fromCurrency.getSelectedItem())`